# C code compilation issue in fedora

Tags: c

Hi guys i am trying to build a jni library. The build is working properly in windows but in linux fedora i am facing an issue its throwing an error like this

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/crtbeginT.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `__DTOR_END__' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

I am compiling the code in this way

```
gcc -o libTest.so -shared -I/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/include -I/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/include/linux arrayUtil.c -static -lc
```

Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong?

This is the error when i call from JNI:

```
Instructions: (pc=0x00002aaaab22627a)
0x00002aaaab22626a:   00 00 48 8b 44 24 18 4d 8b 7e 68 48 8b 5c 24 18
0x00002aaaab22627a:   0f b6 10 48 0f be c2 41 f6 44 47 01 20 74 1c 48

Stack: [0x000000004012b000,0x000000004022c000],  sp=0x000000004022a660,  free space=3fd0000000000000018k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libc.so.6+0x3527a]

[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xb]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.utils.ArrayUtils.setup(Ljava/lang/String;)I+0
j  com.utils.ArrayUtils.init(Ljava/lang/String;)V+245
j  com.utils.ArrayUtils.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00002aaacff55000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5624, stack(0x0000000040832000,0x0000000040933000)]
  0x00002aaacff52800 JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5623, stack(0x0000000040731000,0x0000000040832000)]
  0x00002aaacff4d800 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5622, stack(0x0000000040630000,0x0000000040731000)]
  0x00002aaacff4b800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5621, stack(0x000000004052f000,0x0000000040630000)]
  0x00002aaacff28000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5620, stack(0x000000004042e000,0x000000004052f000)]
  0x00002aaacff26000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5619, stack(0x000000004032d000,0x000000004042e000)]
=>0x0000000040111800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=5617, stack(0x000000004012b000,0x000000004022c000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00002aaacff21800 VMThread [stack: 0x000000004022c000,0x000000004032d000] [id=5618]
  0x00002aaacff58000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000040933000,0x0000000040a34000] [id=5625]
```

Comment: Add -`fPIC` to your `gcc` command, as the error suggests?

Comment: @hmjd: i did try that..but then also i am getting the same error

Comment: @hmjd: i added the -fpic like this gcc -o libTest.so -shared -fPIC -I.. Is it ok?

Comment: Did you perform a clean before recompiling?

Comment: @hmjd: since the error was coming there was nothing there to clean up.

Comment: Note that is a linker error, not a compiler error so there may be previously compiled objects.

Comment: @hmjd: i created a new workspace and i tried that still its giving the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `-static` from your compilation command. `-static` should not be used to build shared objects, it is used to build statically linked executables.

Check [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) for more information on `-static` and the linker.

Comment: The jni library is getting crashed when i execute from java. "A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002aaaab22627a, pid=5593, tid=1076017488
#
# JRE version: 6.0_21-b06
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.0-b16 mixed mode linux-amd64 )

Comment: Do you have a call stack available?

Comment: Updated my question with the call stack